# Is this possible to use linux server as usb drive?

Tags: linux, usb

Is this possible to mount a linux box as a usb drive through an usb cable which connected to another device.

A linux pc <-- USB CABLE --> another device
Another pc mount the linux pc as a usb flash drive.
Another device could be a pc or TV or anything else which can mount USB flash drive.

Comment: Why USB? What problem are you trying to solve with this strange setup?

Comment: Sounds like they're trying to do what Android can do when you plug it into a computer it appears as a memory stick, but to also be able to plug it into a USB ready TV, for example... To watch films etc.

Comment: @BigChris Yes, you're right. that's my intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. USB hosts and devices are generally not interchangeable. You're connecting two hosts together, and that generally isn't something that works

There are [usb *data transfer* cables](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=usb%20data%20transfer%20cable), but these are usb devices with two ends, sitting between two hosts and require additional drivers.

Macintoshes often have [target disk mode](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Target_Disk_Mode), but this is not over USB (though this is [supportable in theory, though most implementations seem to be on PDAs and other SOCs](https://superuser.com/questions/468541/how-can-i-use-target-mode-in-linux-with-usb)
).

You're probably better off transferring files over lan or getting an external HDD.